# add css or color to item when selected from datalist

Tags: asp.net

I had datalist and My manager told me when user select item in datalist this item must have css or color .I did my code but it didnot work well and this error apeared (    Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType` and `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType` )

```
protected void DataList3_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    {
       if (e.Item.ItemType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           e.Item.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
           e.Item.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";

           e.Item.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.DataList3, "Select$" + e.Item.ItemIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To properly format your code, in the editing window, select it all and press the 101010 button, or Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.Item` is a `DataListItem`; if you check [its ItemType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalistitem.itemtype.aspx), you'll see that it's a ListItemType, so you should use that enumeration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemtype.aspx

Something like:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
```